# Getting a buildable git-tfs

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-tfs

I am trying to modify [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs). However, I cannot seem to get it built.

What I did:

```
1. Read the readme which states for building: 
    1a. Update submodules. git submodule update to get the libgit2sharp dependencies.
    1b. Build with msbuild GitTfs.sln /p:Configuration=debug for the default debug build.
2. clone git-tfs: git clone git@github.com:git-tfs/git-tfs.git
3. git submodule update
```

However, the submodule update doesn't seem to do it's job - it doesn't fetch any sources.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run init before update:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

After that to run the integration tests for git-tfs you will need to get XUnit up and running:

https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Running-the-Unit-Tests

XUnit test runner for VS2012:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099

To run the integration tests then you will have to install the TFS plugins (Team Explorer) for VS2008, 2010 and 2012. But you can just unload those projects (GitTfs.Vs2008, GitTfs.Vs2010 and GitTfs.Vs11) if you don't want to run them. GitTfs.VSFake is a fake for the different Visual Studio versions and that will let you run most of the tests.